# Create Aliases In Bulk?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to join three tables, `products`, `taxes` & `categories`. All these tables have conflicting column names. I'm aware that we get around this conflict by creating aliases.

```
products:
    id
    name
    ...

taxes
    id
    name
    ...

categories
    id
    name
    ...
```

My question is, is there a convenient way to create aliases in bulk? What I mean is something like

```
SELECT products.* as product.*, taxes.* as tax.*, categories.* as category.*
...
```

I would expect the result set to have columns like:

```
product.id, product.name, tax.id, tax.name, ...
```

Or, do I have to stick with something tedious as:

```
SELECT products.id as product_id, products.name as product_name,
       taxes.id as tax_id, taxes.name as tax_name, ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You search for `*` on steroid. Unfortunaltely there is no such functionality in `SQL`.

**Workaround 1:**

Use power of block selection in your favourite text editor(vim,atom,...). Place each column in new row. Block selection to write `AS` and table prefix. Then block selection and copy column names.

**Workaround 2:**

Generate select list using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`:

```
SELECT 
 string_agg(FORMAT('%s.%s AS %s_%s', "table_name",
                   column_name,"table_name", column_name), ', ')
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE "table_name" IN ('products', 'taxes', 'categories');
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cf229/5/0)**</kbd>

You could use `E',\n'` to place each column in new line.

Output:

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                                                                                   string_agg                                                                                   ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ products.id AS products_id, products.name AS products_name, taxes.id AS taxes_id, taxes.name AS taxes_name, categories.id AS categories_id, categories.name AS categories_name ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```